# How can i integrate geofield module in entityform?

Tags: google-maps

[image][image: !st image showing no output]Actually i have to add multiple locations in a form of a route and show it after the submit button in a single map using geofield module. How do i do that???The map should locate multiple markers after submit button in one map with their latitude and longitude... the image mentioned in the second is my first image which i am getting now whereas the image been showed at first should be my output image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a better way to do this the thing i wanted was to create integrate multiple locations in one Maps and display the route.. I created this using a HTML file using HTML,CSS, JavaScript and using Markup module i integrated my code in my Entityform. I is working like a charm.